# How did Ginny Weasley have time to petrify Justin?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

In the *Chamber of Secrets* movie Ginny was studying in the study area, and Harry found Justin minutes later. How did Ginny have time to petrify Justin? Was another student possessed?

Comment: I made a few edits to clarify your question. If you don't like them feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: And [I've closed it as a duplicate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) since this question has already been asked. If you think that your question is not covered by the one I linked, you can edit further to explain the difference.